# lineinfile: Don't insert lines if they already exist

Tags: ansible

It's creating a new file and adding content to it. If a re-run ansible for a second time the text content will be applied again below the lines but overwrite the last line `bantime = 86400`.

What I need it to do, is if the text already is applied, don't add it again. I assume my `regexp` is set wrong.

```
- name: add custom settings 
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/fail2ban/jail.local regexp='^' line='maxretry = 3\nfindtime = 10800\nbantime = 86400' create=yes state=present backrefs=yes
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `lineinfile` [examples](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html):

```
# Add a line to a file if it does not exist, without passing regexp
- lineinfile: dest=/tmp/testfile line="192.168.1.99 foo.lab.net foo"
```

Line with `\n` is not a line, those are multiple lines and they can't be matched on next run as a line. You should add each line as a separate task:

```
- name: add maxretry setting
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/fail2ban/jail.local line='maxretry = 3' create=yes

- name: add findtime setting
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/fail2ban/jail.local line='findtime = 10800' create=yes

- name: add bantime setting
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/fail2ban/jail.local line='bantime = 86400' create=yes
```

Also remove `regexp` and `backerefs` settings, since they are not needed and `state`, since `present` is a default value.

---

However it's better to also pass regexp with setting and the name without value. So if you change setting value, it will replace string in file instead of adding new one, like:

```
- name: add maxretry setting
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/fail2ban/jail.local regexp='^maxretry = ' line='maxretry = 3' create=yes
```

Answer (score 3):

@devoto13's answer is correct. The problem is you're trying to add multiple lines. However, if your requirement is to work with those lines not separately, you could use the [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) module. This would also speed up the play as you only have one single task and not one per line.